# creating a database for a photo gallery with comments

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, social-networking

I am creating a social network and want to have a similar photo gallery to that of facebook.  Im guessing I need to use AJAX but I would like to have a comments section for each photo.  I was just wondering what the best way would be to design a database around this.  Do I just make a table of comments?  Would I run into performance issues because Im sure each user would have more than one photo, so the contents tables will get pretty large. Supposing I had 10 million users and each had a 100 photos that with two comments each that would be 2 billion entries and that is only 10 million users, what would happen if that number grew. This would greatly slow down the website.  I know for now I can just develop something simple like one table but I would like to create something fast and be knowledgeable for the future.  If someone could help me out with this I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "and that is only 10 million users"... I admire your ambition :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 10 million users, you'll have the money to buy more resources to handle the requests :)

I would design a table with the comments, and another for the photos. The two tables are of course joined with a one-to-many relationship.

A good, properly configured, RDMBS won't care to store and select photos along with the comments. That's the db job, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

go for associative array that's what most of social networking sites like facebook etc use 
use somewhat like:

```
photo-gallery:
 {
  photo:
  {
   id:
   caption:
   path:
   comment:
   {
    id:
    commentor-id:
    comment-description:
   }
   comment:
   {
    id:
    commentor-id:
    comment-description:
   }
   .
   ....and so on
  }
 }
```

Comment: That only allows one comment per photo (or else, requires duplicating the caption, id, and path data for each photo comment).

Comment: editted the above db schema now we can have multiple associative arrays for comments inside each image array element